# how to set a dynamic video/quicktime sizes?

Tags: php, video, quicktime

i have a problem. i'm using PHP to build my website and there is a dynamic video content that each time a different video/quicktime will be posted.

the problem that i'm facing is setting the width,height of a video because i have many videos with different sized i want the videos to be posted in their sized i don't want to set width and height to EMBED or OBJECT also i have a problem in "Controller" i have to set the height and width more than the video size so the user can see the video controller.

Any thoughts ?

here is the code that i'm using right now

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="{height}" width="{width}" CONTROLLER="true">
<param name="src" value="{path}">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="type" value="video/quicktime">
<param name="CONTROLLER" value="true">
<embed CONTROLLER="true" src="{path}" height="{height}" width="{width}" autoplay="true" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.opencampus.com/faculty/tutorials/QT-html.html) if you omit the height and width attributes the player should auto scale to the source video.